# Creating a unique concrete wall of breeze block and a rough fill

Tags: modeling, texturing

How to make a wall of breeze block and a rough fill of pink grout like in the picture.

Any suggestions about how can I make this grout fill to look like that?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If it's acceptable to do this at render-time, then *Vector Displacement*, masked by the shipped *Brick* texture, and suitably mapped to bias downward in Y, can give you a very reasonable result, shader-only.

[image]

If you wanted it super-refined for extreme close-up, then I think you'd have to have more control, and make your own brick-tiling from scratch.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Create a segment and array it on X and Z, like for example 4 times:

[image]

Give it a *Displace* modifier with a *Cloud* texture to give it random bumps:

[image]

Apply the *Array* modifier, move down some faces:

[image]

Give it again an *Array* modifier on X to repeat the 4 segments, the repetition of the segments will probably not be noticeable. Add some procedural bumps with a Noise Texture plugged into a *Bump* node plugged into the *Normal* input of your shader.

Answer (score 3):

While I like moonboots answer more, I just wanted to show an alternative as I was playing with fluids today and your photo seemed like "Mortar ooze".

Here I used a brick array as a fluid Effector collision and adjusted the Fluid Domain viscosity, diffusion, and resolution to get the following at frame 23:

[image]

You could call this "the absurd approach"?  [image]

Comment: Thank you guys for all the response!! this will be fun to do! i think Im going to try all methods just to see what comes up! thanks again